# Simple html dom вытащить ссылки из под javascript

Tags: php

Существует слайдер с картинками в javascript. 
Требуется вытащить оттуда ссылки на картинки с помощью [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser).
Как пробраться внутрь `<script type="text/javascript">` чтобы спарсить - не пойму.

Вот код из javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fotoOptions = {
        width: '100%',
        ratio: 1920/800,
        data: [
            {video: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/exGOtsiS0tw"},
            {img: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3992.jpg", thumb: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3992.jpg"},
            {img: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3991.jpg", thumb: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3991.jpg"},
            {img: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3990.jpg", thumb: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3990.jpg"},
            {img: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3989.jpg", thumb: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3989.jpg"},
            {img: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3988.jpg", thumb: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3988.jpg"},
            {img: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3987.jpg", thumb: "http://img14.torrentino.me/images/gamescreenshot/3/3987.jpg"},
        ]
    }
</script>
```

3 дня уже мучаюсь, не могу вытащить ссылки на картинки.

Comment: Как вы в PHP достаете этот Javascript код и куда помещаете - в массив, строку или объект? Добавьте это в вопрос, пожалуйста. А еще лучше отредактируйте чтобы получить минимально возможный воспроизводимый код, к примеру, в http://phpfiddle.org/

Answer (score 1):

Вот так достанете все, что находится в теге  скрипт.

```
   foreach($html->find('*[text/javascript]') as $scrimage){
    echo $scrimage; // вывод картинок
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

Потом из полученных данных выберите то, что нужно.

Вот вам код, который вытащит каждую картинку в отдельную переменную:

```
    preg_match_all(
'/{img: "(.+?)"/',
$scrimage,
$m
);
echo $img1 = $m[1][0];
echo $img2 = $m[1][1];
echo $img3 = $m[1][2];
echo $img4 = $m[1][3];
echo $img5 = $m[1][4];
echo $img6 = $m[1][5];
```

Comment: Можете помочь с [похожей проблемой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1066824/15479)?