# Парсинг <script type=“text/javascript”> на php

Tags: php

Создал парсер

В html документе есть код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player = new Playerjs({
        id:"videoplayer2535",
        file:"https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/hls/index.m3u8",
        poster:"https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/screen.jpg",
        subtitle:"",
    });
</script>
```

Как средствами парсера вытянуть ссылку

```
https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/hls/index.m3u8
```

Пробовал так

```
$stream = $one_dom->find('script[type=text/javascript]', 0);
```

Подскажите решение.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения

Javascript

```
let text=`
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player = new Playerjs({
        id:"videoplayer2535",
        file:"https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/hls/index.m3u8",
        poster:"https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/screen.jpg",
        subtitle:"",
    });`;
let re = /file:"(.*?)",/;
let result = text.match(re);
document.write(result[1]);
```

php

```
$text = '<script type="text/javascript">
    var player = new Playerjs({
        id:"videoplayer2535",
        file:"https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/hls/index.m3u8",
        poster:"https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/screen.jpg",
        subtitle:"",
    });
</script>';


preg_match('/file:"(.*?)",/', $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches[0][0]);
```

`/file:"(.*?)",/;` искомая строка начинается с `file:"` далее группа в скобках: любые символы `.*` ? лечит квантификатор * от жадности. `",` конец группы.

Comment: Я думаю автору нужно решение на php. Кажется он юзает Simple HTML DOM Parser, но могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = '<script type="text/javascript">
  var player = new Playerjs({
    id: "videoplayer2535",
    file:"https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/hls/index.m3u8",
    poster: "https://ashdi.vip/content/stream/films/zavtra_ne_pomre_nkoli_2535/screen.jpg",
    subtitle: "",
  });
</script>';

preg_match('/file:"\K[^"]+/', $text, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

https://3v4l.org/eJYOt